# React useState hook issue on updating real time data inside MQTT communication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, mqtt

##### Story

I'm showing a lot of real-time location data in a map using React Js with MQTT communication. You can imagine it like a dashboard to show all Uber's drivers real-time location.

I have 7 devices that broadcast their data into Rabbit MQ server. In the Rabbit MQ, I install MQTT plugin so I can retrieve data from Rabbit MQ server using MQTT in React.

The data from every device is broadcast at a random time. So there can be no data in a second and there are a lot of data from some devices in a second.

Let's say this one is the example data broadcasted from one device once:

```json
{ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}

or:

{ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 3, device.name: "Device-3", device.type.id: 579, …}
```

##### Target

What I want to do:

1. Filter every item (broadcasted from a device): Let's say I have an `array` to store every device. Because I have 7 devices, so I will have an `array` with a length of 7.

- If the item has a device id that is not found in the `array`, the item is added into the `array`.
- If the item has a device id that is found in the `array`, the item will replace the old item (with the same device id) in the array.

2. Update the `data` (state variables) with `array` using `useState` hook.

##### Code

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import mqtt from 'mqtt'

export default function RealtimeMarker() {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([])
    let array = []

    const usingMqtt = () => {
        const url = 'ws://blahblahblah/ws'
        const client = mqtt.connect(url)
        const topicsToSubscribe = 'message/devices/+' // '+' is a wildcard
        
        client.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected')
        client.subscribe(topicsToSubscribe)
        })

        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            const itemMessage = JSON.parse(message.toString())
            console.log('itemMessage: ', itemMessage)

            // ADD NEW ITEM TO EMPTY DATA
            if(data.length === 0) {
                array.push(itemMessage)
            }
            // ADD NEW ITEM TO NON-EMPTY DATA
            else {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if(data[i]['device.id'] !== itemMessage['device.id'] && itemMessage['ble.beacons'] === null) {
                        array.push(itemMessage)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            setData(array)
        })
    }

    console.log('data: ', data.length, data)

    useEffect(() => {
        usingMqtt()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`+` in the topic `'message/devices/+'` is a wildcard for all topics.

dependencies:

```
"mqtt": "^4.2.8",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
```

environment:

```
OS: Windows 10 Home
NPM: v6.14.8
Node: v12.9.0
```

##### Problem:

The `data` variable is only updated twice forever like this log.

```
10:29:46.179 RealtimeMarker.js:65 data:  0 []
10:29:46.326 RealtimeMarker.js:34 connected
10:29:46.610 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:29:46.611 RealtimeMarker.js:65 data:  1 [{…}]
10:29:48.845 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.046, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:48.846 RealtimeMarker.js:65 data:  2 (2) [{…}, {…}]
10:29:49.021 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.043, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:49.022 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.041, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:49.023 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.048, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:49.024 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.033, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:51.946 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.071, …}
10:29:53.236 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.006, …}
10:29:53.410 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.007, …}
10:29:53.410 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 3, device.name: "Device-3", device.type.id: 579, …}
10:29:53.410 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.6, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:29:53.410 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 3, device.name: "Device-3", device.type.id: 579, …}
10:29:53.411 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.6, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:29:56.570 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:29:58.468 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.048, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:29:58.637 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.041, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:01.984 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.067, …}
10:30:03.177 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:03.353 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.008, …}
10:30:03.354 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.608, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:03.354 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.512, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:03.354 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.512, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:06.771 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:11.039 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.05, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:11.238 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.037, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:11.415 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.735, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:11.416 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.735, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:11.417 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.746, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:11.418 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.785, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:11.585 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.754, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:11.585 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:11.586 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 5, device.name: "Device-5", device.type.id: 579, …}
10:30:12.462 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.008, …}
10:30:12.636 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:12.636 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.512, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:12.636 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.558, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:12.637 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.549, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:16.475 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:21.963 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.067, …}
10:30:22.577 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.006, …}
10:30:22.749 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:22.750 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 3, device.name: "Device-3", device.type.id: 579, …}
10:30:22.751 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.595, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:22.752 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.562, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:26.452 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:31.486 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.067, …}
10:30:32.226 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:32.401 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.006, …}
10:30:32.401 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.571, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:32.402 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.567, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:32.402 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.578, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:34.401 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.039, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:34.568 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.039, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
10:30:36.795 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:40.088 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.854, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.011, …}
10:30:40.248 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.553, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:40.248 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.556, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:40.248 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.553, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:40.248 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.553, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
10:30:41.425 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:41.599 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ble.beacons: Array(0), channel.id: 10476, device.id: 5, device.name: "Device-5", device.type.id: 579, …}
10:30:44.862 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.735, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:45.023 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.735, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:45.024 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.746, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:45.024 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.785, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:45.024 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.754, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
10:30:46.328 RealtimeMarker.js:42 itemMessage:  {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.234, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.066, …}
10:30:47.899 RealtimeMarker.js:34 connected
```

As you can see that the `data` is only updated twice although all 7 devices' data is transferred to the React app.

There is one more thing unclear. As you can see that at `10:29:46.611`, the data has a length of 1. If I open the `data`, the `data` has a length more than 1 as seen below:

```
0: {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.974, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
1: {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.968, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
2: {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.972, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
3: {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.97, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
4: {ain.1: 0.173, ain.2: 2.955, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.004, …}
5: {ain.1: 0.087, ain.2: 3.033, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
6: {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.894, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.01, …}
7: {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.887, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.008, …}
8: {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.593, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
9: {ain.1: 0.043, ain.2: 2.589, battery.charging.status: false, battery.current: 0, battery.voltage: 4.03, …}
```

##### Questions

1. How could this happen? What's wrong with my code?
2. How to solve this or achieve the target?

##### Note

If this case is not really clear, please let me know in the comment seciont. I would update the question soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are having issues with closure and mutating state.

As you only register the event handlers on mount your event handler for the `message` event will always have the same reference for `array`.

This means that each time a message is received you are pushing onto the same initial array and storing that same exact same reference into the state.

As the reference doesn't change React will assume that the array has not been updated.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import mqtt from 'mqtt'

export default function RealtimeMarker() {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState([])

    console.log('data: ', data.length, data)

    // Use useEffect to create client and event listener.
    // No need to recreate usingMqtt function on every render.
    useEffect(() => {
        const url = 'ws://blahblahblah/ws'
        const client = mqtt.connect(url)
        const topicsToSubscribe = 'message/devices/+' // '+' is a wildcard
        
        client.on('connect', () => {
            console.log('connected')
            client.subscribe(topicsToSubscribe);
        })

        client.on('message', (topic, message) => {
            const itemMessage = JSON.parse(message.toString())
            console.log('itemMessage: ', itemMessage)
            
            // make use of alternate syntax of setState to ensure you are always using
            // newest state values.
            setData(currentData => {
                // Create an array with a new reference.
                // Without a new reference react assumes there is no change to the array.
                let array = [...currentData]

                if(currentData.length === 0) {
                    array.push(itemMessage)
                }
                else {
                    let found = 0
                    for(let i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
                        console.log(currentData[i]['device.id'], itemMessage['device.id'], itemMessage['ble.beacons'])
                        if(currentData[i]['device.id'] === itemMessage['device.id']) {
                            found++
                            currentData[i] = itemMessage
                        }
                    }

                    if(found === 0) {
                        array.push(itemMessage)
                    }
                }

                return array
            })
        })

        //Ensure client is closed on unmount of component.
        return () => {
            client.end();
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You're right that I forget about the closure and mutating state. I tried to use your code but I found another issue with the code. The ```data``` or the ```array``` variable was never updated. It only contained the first item/message read from the MQTT server.

Comment: I have changed the ```[setData]``` (parameter for the ```useEffect``` hook) into ```[data]``` or ```[]``` (empty parameter) but still the same.

Comment: I found the solution to meet the targets. Let me update your answer in order to make a note for us especially me. Thank you.